# handshake_failure issue with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Getting the below error while connecting a slave machine to the Jenkins Server. Seems related to certs. Any body knows how to fix it.

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1781)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1024)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1235)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1219)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:440)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.parseJnlpArguments(Launcher.java:268)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:218)
        at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:192)